# A `return` is needed after `context.res` to stop execution

Tags: azure-functions

During Azure Function (AF) debugging, I noticed the both statements `context.res={...}` and `context.res.send()` won't end the execution and send back response. To test I create a brand new AF, take the auto-generated files and test using *Postman*. It goes well.

I then add a new line at the begining:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.res = {body:"line 1"};     // alone won't end execution 
    context.res.send({body:"send()"};  // send() calls .done() implicitly per MS, still won't end.
    context.done();           // needed by sync, thought would do anyway, but neither
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    ...       // executed
    return;   // lastly it ends here
    var x = 1;  // never reach.
}
```

However, explicit `return;` is not mentioned in [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2). Is it true `return` is required if to end execution in the middle?

Comment: In functions, my understanding is that yes a call to return will then bundle up the response with all headers, etc. and send it back to the calling application.  I think you'll find the response happens external to your function, i.e. the higher level framework, otherwise, it's not going to know what to do once it exits your function.  The returned value is what it will take and send back to the caller.  You're not in charge of handling the transmission, the AF framework is.  That's my take on it.

Comment: I would add that I think this is especially true for an `async` function. The documentation isn't worded very clearly, but there is an indication that `return` is required for `async`, and while I haven't thought much about it, every function I've written ends with a `return`.

Comment: @Skin My point is `context.res()` is similar to regular javascript `res.send()` which ends the execution inside of current function, no `return` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run/Execute some line of code in your function you have only function level access, not function execution level access. So, whatever you want to do in your function you need to do it before function execution.

```js
    module.exports = async function (context, req) {    
        context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
        context.log('started and finised the context here');
        
        //Function execution Finishing point has context.res
        
        context.res.send({body: "Insert succeeded."});
        
        //After Fuction exection we can do some execution but it was function level not in a context level
        // while using async function we dont want to use context.done() & return untill is necessary
        
        var x = 1;
        console.log("X values is: "+x);
        
        //You can use return statement if you want to send any return value.
        //return;
    }
```

[image]
In your azure function use the async azure function. To call async and await helps to avoid major two problems. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#use-async-and-await) to how efficiently use async and await in your function.

**Note:**
In Azure function not even run a single line of execution after return statement.

> A `return` is needed after `context.res` to stop execution

Return is not necessary after the **context.res**.

### Updated Explanation:

- Context will not work after the function finishing point which are `context.res` / `context.res.send`.
- When exporting an `async` function, `return` keyword is not needed until you have any output binding to return it.

Comment: Glad your code demonstrates exactly my finding, but your explanation not explaining.

Comment: please check the updated answer

Comment: Appreciate input. But it does not answer the question.